# como agregar un boton dentro de un if else

Tags: php, mysqli

Hola buenas tardes tengo una consulta que me cuenta si una persona ya tiene anotaciones. en el caso de que si tenga anotaciones me debe mostrar un boton y si no tiene anotaciones me debe mostrar otro boton. cada boton direcciona a una pagina diferente. tengo el siguente codigo. pero no logro que funcione.

primero me lista la informacion, luego me cuenta si la persona tiene alguna anotacion . pero en el if no logro que funcione.

```
<?php
        
            $query = "SELECT * FROM mat_2022 WHERE mat_estado='1' ORDER BY curso ASC;";
            $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
            while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
            ?>  
                <tr>
                    <td><?php 
                            $rut = $row['runalu'];
                            echo $rut; ?></td>
                                            
                    <td><?php echo $row['nombresalu']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['apellidosalu']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['nivel']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['curso']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['especialidad']; ?></td>
                    
                    <td>
                        <?php
                            require_once("connection.php");
                                    $querya = "SELECT * FROM atenciones WHERE runalu = '$rut' AND estado = '1'";
                                    $resulta = mysqli_query($con,$querya);
                                    $numeroa = mysqli_num_rows($resulta); 
                                    echo ''.$numeroa.'';
                            
                        
                            $numeroa  != 0;
                            if($numeroa){
                                echo '<input type="button" value="REGISTRO NUEVO" onClick="window.location='datos_generales_nuevo.php?rut=<?php echo $rut; ?>';">';
                            }else{
                                echo '<input type="button" value="REGISTRO ANTIGUO" onClick="window.location='datos_generales_antiguo.php?rut=<?php echo $rut; ?>';">';
                            }
                        ?>
                            

                    </td>
                    
                    
                    
                    
                    
        <?php
        }       
        ?>
```

Comment: La condición del if esta mal estructurado si no me equivoco. Tendría que ir así `if($numeroa != 0)`.

Comment: No es buena idea mezclar HTML y PHP, dificulta demasiado la lectura e identificación de errores, indenta tu código y revisa el primer **While**.

Comment: El problema esta cuando trato de incorporar los botones

Answer (score 1):

Tu problema es que estas haciendo lo siguiente

```
$numeroa  != 0;
 if($numeroa){
```

Deberias buscar sobre los [operador de comparacion en php](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.operators.comparison.php) , pero para responder a tu pregunta, esto `$numeroa  != 0;` debe ir dentro del if, no por fuera quedando `if($numeroa != 0){` ya que haciendolo en la manera actual simplemente esta tratando de "declarar", pero eso nisiquiera de declarar, ya que `!=` funciona como un operador de comparación que debe ser utilizado dentro de un if o un for etc..

Comment: El problema esta cuando trato de incorporar los botones

Comment: Es lo que te está diciendo ernesto... has de quitar la línea `$numeroa =! 0;`, que no tiene sentido, y cambiar el if siguiente por `if($numeroa == 0) {` para comprobar que si el número de anotaciones es 0 ponga un botón y si no el otro. Además, entiendo que ya habías hecho `require_once("connection.php");` antes del primer `SELECT`, así que no lo utilices de nuevo para el segundo y la conexión ya está abierta.

Comment: @JAGR si despues de esto aun sigues teniendo problemas para incorporar los botones entonces tienes un problema de logica, ya que el codigo esta diciendo que si ```$numeroa``` NO ES IGUAL A 0 quiere decir que hay datos

Comment: @JAGR Ademas lo que dice VFG tiene razón, si al principio colocaste un SELECT significa que ya abriste la conexion a la bd, entonces no tienes que volver a llamar el archivo de conexion más abajo porque eso puede traer problemas

Comment: el segundo select es para una consulta en otra base de datos

Answer (score 0):

ya encontre la respuesta a mi problema, solo cambie la forma en la que se redireccionan a otra pagina. de onClick a href. LES AGRADESCO SU PARTICIACION.

```
if($numeroa == 0) {
        echo '<a href="plantilla.php?rut='.$rut.'">Primera Atencion</a>';
    }else{
        echo '<a href="segunda_atencion.php?rut='.$rut.'">Segunda Atencion</a>';

                                    }
```